# Custom Button For Record Creation

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have a requirement to use custom button for record Creation of an object where i'll do some custom logic and it should ideally match the standard record creation Pop up . I can create a lightning component for that but the only thing is we can create custom button with Visualforce , so how do i make the component as kind of Standard New button component in lightning where we get a Pop up to fill our fields and everything.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know how to accomplish this programmatically, but it is possible with a few clicks.
Use custom Global Actions to call a Lightning Component to create a new record without a relationship to another record:

> Use a Visualforce page, Lightning component, or a canvas app to create global custom actions for tasks that don’t require users to use records that have a relationship to a specific object...To call Lightning components from custom actions, you must have My Domain deployed in your org.
> [Global Quick Actions | Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.actions_overview_global.htm&type=5)

Use custom Object Specific Quick Actions to create a record with a relationship to another record.

> [Create Object-Specific Quick Actions | Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.creating_object_specific_actions.htm&type=5)